# NullPointerException when trying to access inherited field

Tags: android, kotlin

I`m getting NPE when trying to access overridden variable in parent class

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at app.deadmc.materiallivewallpaper.model.Square.<init>(Square.kt:29)
at app.deadmc.materiallivewallpaper.model.Cube.<init>(Cube.kt:8)
at app.deadmc.materiallivewallpaper.renderer.MaterialRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(MaterialRenderer.kt:40)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1548)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1286)
```

I will show simplified code for undestanding problem

I have a class for drawing square

```
open class Square(renderer: ReadyRenderer) {
    val COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3

    open val triangleCoords = floatArrayOf(
            //first triangle
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            //second triangle
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)

    private val vertexCount:Int = triangleCoords.size / COORDS_PER_VERTEX

    init {
        val bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                triangleCoords.size * 4)
        //other code
    }
}
```

Square works correctly, but now I want to draw Cube, so I just inherit from Square and add more coordinates

```
open class Cube(renderer: ReadyRenderer):Square(renderer) {    
    val size = 1.0f
    override val triangleCoords = floatArrayOf(
            //front side
            // Triangle 1
            -size, size, size, // top-left
            -size, -size, size, // bottom-left
            size, -size, size, // bottom-right
            // Triangle 2
            size, -size, size, // bottom-right
            size, size, size, // top-right
            -size, size, size, // top-left
        //and then back side, left, top, right with same way
)
}
```

Seems logic, right? All variables have values and there should be no place for NPE.

But when I try to create instance of Cube

```
 val cube = Cube(this@MaterialRenderer)
```

I catch NullPointerException in Square class at this line:

```
private val vertexCount:Int = triangleCoords.size / COORDS_PER_VERTEX
```

Even if I assign value directly like

```
private val vertexCount:Int = 2
```

I will get NPE at Square class inside init block at this line:

```
val bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
        triangleCoords.size * 4)
```

So I have 2 questions:

**1. How can I fix it and still use inheritance?**

**2. Is it really supposed to work that way?**

Comment: It seems that a cube is not a square, but a cube consists of squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the editor, it actually warned you using non-final property in constructor. This happens because when you create `Cube`, it need to create a `Square` first. When `Square` is creating, `Cube` is **NOT** initialized. (`triangleCoords` is null) Therefore, `triangleCoords.size` will throw exception.

> How can I fix it and still use inheritance?

You should pass it as parameter.

```
open class Square(protected val triangleCoords: FloatArray = floatArrayOf(
        //first triangle
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        //second triangle
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)) {
    val COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3

    private val vertexCount: Int = triangleCoords.size / COORDS_PER_VERTEX

    init {
        val bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                triangleCoords.size * 4)
        //other code
    }
}

open class Cube(val size: Float = 1.0f) : Square(floatArrayOf(
        //front side
        // Triangle 1
        -size, size, size, // top-left
        -size, -size, size, // bottom-left
        size, -size, size, // bottom-right
        // Triangle 2
        size, -size, size, // bottom-right
        size, size, size, // top-right
        -size, size, size, // top-left
        //and then back side, left, top, right with same way
)) {
}
```

If you think this is ugly, you can write a factory method and pass the array through parameter to a private constructor.

> Is it really supposed to work that way?

Yes

Comment: @DEADMC As I mentioned, you can use a factory method.

Comment: with replacing coordinates to another util file its not that bad =)